# How can I check for the absence of a key and write one if it does not exist?

Tags: ios, swift

The code below's purpose is to log a user in, and generate a random string as an identifier for the device, however I am having trouble figuring out a way to check if the user has already gotten an ID and it has been saved as a key.

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    //generates string as ID for licencing
    func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {

        let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

        var randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

        for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
            var length = UInt32 (letters.length)
            var rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
            randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
        }

        return randomString
    }


    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var secretKey = ""
    var team:NSString = teamID.text
    var scout:NSString = scoutID.text
    var password:NSString = pinNumber.text
```

if the login is correct the following is executed

```
                    if(success == 1 && secretKey != ""){

                    println("Login SUCCESS w/ key")
                    userDefaults.setValue(team, forKey: "teamid")
                    userDefaults.setValue(scout, forKey: "scout")
                    userDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                    userDefaults.setValue(secretKey, forKey: "secretkey")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)


                } else if success == 1 && secretKey  == "" {
                    var secretKey = randomStringWithLength(15);
                    userDefaults.setValue(team, forKey: "teamid")
                    userDefaults.setValue(scout, forKey: "scout")
                    userDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                    userDefaults.setValue(secretKey, forKey: "secretkey")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
                    println("Login SUCCESS w/o key")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)



                    }
```

Comment: You can not use `NSUserDefaults` for unique user ID. Use `sqlite` database instead.

Comment: Consider storing the identifier in the device keychain. This will stay persisted across app installs

Comment: @Kampai even if it isn't something I am not worried about the user changing? How much more complicated does sqlite get.

Comment: @DanielGalasko I can't figure out how to institute the keychain. Do you have any pointers? Thank you.

Comment: @TylerPatrick take a look at SSkeychain on github:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko Looks simple enough, but is in obj-c. Not something I am super familiar with. I will make an attempt to port it for swift. Thank you :)

Comment: Or just use it as Obj-C. You can mix Obj-C and Swift in the same project. I think it will be eaiser to learn enough Obj-C to use an Obj-C library than it will be to port it to Swift.

Comment: @nielsbot You're right. I just wonder why there hasn't been a more efficient thing made for swift. Any thoughts on https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Comment: no idea about various keychain API wrappers, sorry. You might even try using the C API itself if it's not too complicated... you will have to evaluate that.

Comment: Another option might be the user's icloud storage?

Comment: Objective C isn't going anywhere anytime soon and especially since most of the best libraries out there are written in Obj-C I think a strong working knowledge on  with Swift is an absolute must